# Java - SQLite Web Service Returning Blob

Tags: java, web-services, sqlite, blob

I have a Java web service that is querying a SQLite database that contains blob data. I'm returning sql statements so that consumers of the service can just insert/update/delete with out processing the data. My problem is when I get to the blob data, the sqlite-jdbc driver says that the getBlob function is not implemented. So my question is this doable? Is there a better driver or way to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite supports BLOB datatype. [Sqlitejdbc driver](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) does not support the ResultSet#getBlob() method but BLOBs are supported. Just use ResultSet#getBytes() method. Here is the sample code (I did not put proper exception handling in this code to make it simple):

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SQLiteTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    createTable(statement);
    insertBlob(connection);
    byte[] bytes = query(statement);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
            statement.close();
    connection.close();
}

private static void createTable(Statement statement) throws SQLException {
    statement.execute("CREATE TABLE test (data BLOB)");
}

private static void insertBlob(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pStatement = connection
            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)");
    pStatement.setBytes(1, new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
    pStatement.execute();
    pStatement.close();
}

private static byte[] query(Statement statement) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT data FROM test");
    byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(1);
    return bytes;
}

}
```

Comment: I am using the getBytes() method, however it is NULL terminated and so I'm only getting small bits of data. Do you know of any sqlite drivers that support this function so that I can get the length of the blob?

Comment: Hi Erik, I am not sure how did you put the null into BLOB. It is not possible in Java (because you are getting NullPointerException in such situations). You have some program in different language?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to go a different way with this. Thank you for your time Hakyer!