# byte [] to blob conversion in java using preparedstatement and sqllite

Tags: java, sqlite, blob

I am trying to convert byte [] into blob. My code is as follows

```
        byte [] hashValue = HashClass.hash256Bytes(messageValue);

        //query = "insert into message values (?)";
        connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        //Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(hashValue);
        Blob blob = new SerialBlob(hashValue);
        //blob.setBytes(1, hashValue);

        preStatement = (PreparedStatement)    
        connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preStatement. setBlob(1, blob);
        rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

But its breaking at preStatement. setBlob(4, blob). I have did bit google and tried below code but it give null at connection.createBlob().

```
       Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
       blob.setBytes(1, bytes);
```

Comment: Have you tried to just call `preStatement.setBytes(1, bytes)`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090170/cannot-save-image-as-blob-to-sqlite  Why worry about a BLOB for 256 bytes?

Comment: Add the stacktrace and the query

Comment: null at connection.createBlob(). means connection is not created. add stacktrace or the complete code

Comment: connection.createBlob() is giving null to me and connection object is created. Please find the stack trace.  Exception occurred in target VM: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver 
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver on preStatement. setBlob(1, blob)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9184169/2412663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `setBytes();` method

```
    byte [] hashValue = HashClass.hash256Bytes(messageValue);

    //query = "insert into message values (?)";
    connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    //Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(hashValue);
    //Blob blob = new SerialBlob(hashValue);

    preStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
    preStatement. setBytes(1, hashValue);
    rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: preStatement. setBytes(1, hashValue) give me                                         Exception occurred in target VM: Query does not return results 
java.sql.SQLException: Query does not return results
 at

Comment: what is the query you are executing?? if it is `insert/update/delete query` then execute `preStatement.execute();` method and if `select query` then use `rs = preStatement.executeQuery();` method.