# How to fetch an image(Blob) from SQLite Manager database and transfer it to an iText pdf report?

Tags: java, sqlite, pdf, itext

I'm writing a query that accesses a SQLite Manager database, where my table has two data types: Images & Texts. I'm trying to generate an iText PDF report with the selected Images & Texts (the text part works fine)

```java
//  Code for generating an itext report of selected image
Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("Image1");
byte[] imageBytes = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());
com.itextpdf.text.Image image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(imageBytes);
document.add(image);
```

> java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLiteJDBC driver

Comment: Add the full stack trace. Put it inside code tags so that it is readable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183783/java-sqlite-web-service-returning-blob